# Example of XYS university [graduate/graduates]?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-structure

Shall I use

I will endeavor to be a good example for XYS graduates/graduate?

Which one should I use?

Comment: Would "XYS" be a school (or some other group) in this example?  If so you would use "graduates," if you are referring to more than one of them.  Otherwise, "the XYS graduate" for singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to setting a good example for those people who have graduated from XYS university, you would say:

> I will endeavor to be a good example for XYS graduates.

If you mean you will be a good example *of a person who graduated from XYS* (an "alumnus" or "alumna"), then you would write:

> I will endeavor to be a good example of an XYS graduate.

The difference here is, are you referring to yourself as a graduate (use the singular); or are you referring to the pool of graduates as the object themselves (then use the plural).

---

As a side note, more commonly you might use "set a good example" in the first sentence ("I will set a good example for XYS graduates"), and in the second sentence, "I will endeavor to set a good example as an XYS graduate".